# Reference uploaded JAR library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, databricks

I've billed set of support function into `helper.jar` library and imported to Databricks cluster. The jar is installed on the cluster, but I'm not able to reference the functions in the library.

The jar import has been tested, cluster restarted and the jar can be referenced in InelliJ where it was developed as Azure Spark/HDInsight project.

```
//next line generates error value helper is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import helper 

//nex line generates error: not found: value fn_conversion 
display(df.withColumn("RevenueConstantUSD", fn_conversion($"Revenue"))
```

I'd expect the `helper` function would be visible after library deployment or possibly after adding the `import` command.

*Edit: added information about IntelliJ project type*

Comment: Did you add a package definition to your library? for example: `com.yourcompany.yourproject.helper`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you fore recommendation, I didn't think about this. Where would you put this - JAR manifest file or somewhere else? Which property would be assigned this information?

Comment: On every file of your library. It is usually the first code line. And also remember that your directory structure should match the package name. Then, after building and importing your jar, you should be able to import your classes using their full names. For example `import com.yourcompany.yourproject.helper.HelperClassA`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez , used your recommendation to define path and package as you've suggested (in my case `com.edgfbi`). Also added the company into build definition. The change didn't helped to my original project, but it's useful after refactoring it and using SBT build.

Comment: I'm sorry it did not solve your problem. It is kind of weird, if Spark has the **JAR** on its _classpath_ it should be able to find your classes.